Monitors on Docking Station nnot being recognised
I have just bought an ASUS Zenbook 14 UX5406S ultra 7 258v and a Kensington SD4850P USB-C Dual video driver-less dock and I'm having problems with the monitors being recognised in Ubuntu 24.10
I have tried it in Windows 11 (I have a dual boot setup) and it works fine. If I use it with Ubuntu it hardly ever works. Occasionally it does but 95+% of the time it doesn't. I haven't been able to work out why it does occasionally work, there doesn't seem to be any pattern
I have tried turning the docking station on and off, resetting it and changing which monitors are plugged in and it still doesn't work. I've tried installing the synaptic displaylink drivers (https://www.synaptics.com/products/d...wnloads/ubuntu) and deleting ~/.config/monitors.xml, logging out and trying again. Still doesn't work
If I do "lsusb" it shows the dock:
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 047d:80ac Kensington USB3.1 Hub
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 047d:80ae Kensington USB3.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 047d:80b0 Kensington USB3.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 2109:0210 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 002 Device 012: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
Bus 002 Device 013: ID 047d:806e Kensington USB Storage
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 3277:0059 Shinetech ASUS FHD webcam
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:0037 Intel Corp.
Bus 003 Device 014: ID 047d:80ab Kensington USB2.0 Hub
Bus 003 Device 015: ID 047d:80ad Kensington USB2.0 Hub
Bus 003 Device 016: ID 046d:c548 Logitech, Inc. Logi Bolt Receiver
Bus 003 Device 017: ID 047d:80af Kensington USB2.0 Hub
Bus 003 Device 018: ID 2109:2210 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 019: ID 046d:081d Logitech, Inc. HD Webcam C510
Bus 003 Device 020: ID 046d:0893 Logitech, Inc. StreamCam
Bus 003 Device 021: ID 047d:808d Kensington SD4850P USB-C Dual Video Dock
Bus 003 Device 022: ID 0bda:48f0 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB Audio
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

If I go to Privacy and Security it has Direct Access turned on. Doesn't show the dock but I assume this is because this is for Thunderbolt and I'm using a USB-C dock.
